# Liip Imagine generates wrong remove path on listener event in Symfony 5

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5, liipimaginebundle

I'm using [Liip Imagine Bundle](https://github.com/liip/LiipImagineBundle) for Symfony 5. I've got it configured, the images are generated and show properly.

However, I have an issues on an event listener for `postUpdate` and `preRemove` where I want to delete the image.

The listener itself works fine, but Liip Imagine generates the wrong path for the storage, and thus I'm stuck with hundreds of images that never get deleted properly.

My config is fairly standard:

```
parameters:
  img_path: "/public/assets/img/uploaded"
  display_img_path: "/assets/img/uploaded/"
  google_secret_key: '%env(GOOGLE_KEY)%'
  site_name: '%env(SITE_NAME)%'
  liip_img_cache_path: '/media/cache'
liip_imagine:
  resolvers:
    default:
      web_path:
        web_root: "%kernel.project_dir%/public"
        cache_prefix: "%liip_img_cache_path%"
  filter_sets:
    cache: ~
    listing_show_thumbnails:
      quality: 60
      filters:
        thumbnail: { size: [ 450 ], mode: outbound, allow_upscale: true }
    user_profile_public_thumbnail:
      quality: 60
      filters:
        thumbnail: { size: [ 600 ], mode: outbound, allow_upscale: true }
    add_single_thumbnail:
      quality: 60
      filters:
        thumbnail: { size: [ 300 ], mode: outbound, allow_upscale: true }
    add_single_thumbnail_carousel:
      quality: 80
      filters:
        thumbnail: { size: [ 800 ], mode: outbound, allow_upscale: true }
```

And they way the listener is setup is also standard.

```
class CacheImageListener
{
    protected $cacheManager;
    protected $parameterBag;

    public function __construct(CacheManager $cacheManager, ParameterBagInterface $parameterBag)
    {
        $this->cacheManager = $cacheManager;
        $this->parameterBag = $parameterBag;
    }

    public function postUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        //... some other stuff here
    }

    public function preRemove(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = $args->getEntity();
        if ($entity instanceof UserImage) {
            if($this->cacheManager->isStored($entity->getPath(), 'user_profile_public_thumbnail')) {
                $this->cacheManager->remove($entity->getPath(), 'user_profile_public_thumbnail');
            }
        }
        // other functions bellow
```

The path generated by the fucntion

`$this->cacheManager->isStored...`

is

`C:\Bitnami\wampstack-7.4.9-0\apps\coleg/public/media/cache/user_profile_public_thumbnail/6012e6dbf4cad3416fb609e343470c27778f491dd1debc238fa2d9b3676fae007cc439bcb912feaca006db1bc23a6d17759e.jpeg`

The first part is correct(`C:\Bitnami\wampstack-7.4.9-0\apps\coleg/public/media/cache/user_profile_public_thumbnail/`) but the rest is not.

The folder structures is like so

Basically it's missing the "suffix", I suppose you'd call it. Meaning the `assets/img/uploaded` which is where I store my original images.

---

I'm pretty sure I have something misconfigured somewhere but I can't put my finger on it.

[image]

Comment: by looking at your code you are just removing from cache but not unlink the actual file at its absolute path

Comment: `$this->cacheManager->remove($entity->getPath(), 'user_profile_public_thumbnail')` is the removal from the absolute path, but the path is wrong.